# ValueError: X has 25 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 26 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deployment

I am trying to deploy my ML model. I used flask API to do this. Everything is working fine but when I try to predict my ml model on the web it is showing the following error: `ValueError: X has 25 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 26 features as input.` Below code is my `model.py` file in which I trained the model.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix , classification_report
import pickle

train = pd.read_csv("train_data_evaluation_part_2.csv", index_col=False)
test = pd.read_csv("test_data_evaluation_part2.csv", index_col=False)
df = pd.concat([train,test],axis=0)

def unique_obj_col_value(df):
  for column in df:
    if df[column].dtype == 'object':
      print(f'{column}: {df[column].unique()}')

unique_obj_col_value(df)

df = df.drop('Nationality', axis=1)

df['BookingsCheckedIn'] = df['BookingsCheckedIn'].replace([ 3,  1, 9,  2, 11, 12,  7,  8,  5,  6,  4, 66, 15, 29, 25, 10,
   17, 13, 26, 23, 57, 40, 18, 14, 24, 19, 20, 34], 1)

cols = ['DistributionChannel', 'MarketSegment']
le = LabelEncoder()
for col in cols:
df[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col])

pickle.dump(le, open('transform.pkl', 'wb'))

df.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'ID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['Age'].fillna(np.mean(df['Age']),inplace=True)

X = df.drop('BookingsCheckedIn', axis=1)
y = df['BookingsCheckedIn']

cols_to_scale = ['Age','DaysSinceCreation', 'AverageLeadTime', 'LodgingRevenue', 'OtherRevenue','DaysSinceLastStay', 'DaysSinceFirstStay']
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X[cols_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(X[cols_to_scale])
print(X.shape)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.score(X_test,y_test)

yp = clf.predict(X_test)
yp[:5]

y_pred = []
for element in yp:
   if element > 0.5:
      y_pred.append(1)
   else:
      y_pred.append(0)


print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))

pickle.dump(clf, open('model1.pkl', 'wb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))
```

The below code is my `app.py` where flask is used.

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))
trans = pickle.load(open('transform.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    '''
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    '''
    features = [x for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(features, dtype=float)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Booked: ${}'.format(output))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, How do I get rid of that error? Here is the image of the error for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with my Html file. I missed one of the features. That is the reason I am getting this error!